# Index guidance for specific scenario

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please see the SQL below:

```
select count(*) from dbcomplete2_all
inner join dbusns on dbcomplete2_all.urns = dbusns.urns and dbcomplete2_all.datasetname = dbusns.datasetname
where dbusns.cro<>dbcomplete2_all.cro
```

dbcomplete2_all and dbusns contain 55 million records each.  I am trying to figure out the best way to index the two tables.  I believe this is the best way:

```
CREATE INDEX URNsDatasetNameCRO
ON dbcomplete2_all (URNs,DatasetName,CRO)

CREATE INDEX URNsDatasetNameCRO
ON dbUSNS(URNs,DatasetName,CRO)
```

The query runs in one minute.  However, I have also tried this:

```
CREATE INDEX URNsDatasetNameCRO
ON dbcomplete2_all (URNs,DatasetName)

CREATE INDEX URNsDatasetNameCRO
ON dbUSNS(URNs,DatasetName)
```

The query use to run in two minutes with the second set of indexes.  Now it runs in about the same.  Which way is "better"?

Comment: What happens if the index is created like: `CREATE INDEX URNsDatasetNameCRO ON dbcomplete2_all (URNs,DatasetName) INCLUDE (cro);`?

Comment: need to explain what primary keys you have and look at execution plan to see if there are any key lookups and index scans. Next need to consider filtered index and also consider changing query to using not exists instead of not equal operator.

Comment: @Vladimir Oselsky, the primary key is an auto increment field of type integer. How is not equal faster?

Comment: if you are unable to join on primary keys do consider using index that @Lamak provided. If first index still runs faster, just stick to that, but it is possible that moving it to `INCLUDE` will improve it. Also when you look at actual execution plans for the second set of indexes you should probably see `key look-up` because you do not have that column available from the index it self.

Answer (score 0):

Your second set of indexes will cause Key Lookup because `CRO` is not included. **The first one is better** since it has all the columns included in the query. However, indexes ain't free lunch. Every insert/update into the table will cause an insert/update to the index. Balance the insert/update performance with your `SELECT` performance.